# Is it possible to calculate distance by land transport between two UK postcodes using Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to calculate distance by land transport between two UK postcodes using Google Maps API V3? Has anyone accomplished this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions

There is a part that describes what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints.html

You should be able to easily manipulate it to your needs.